# _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-background"

Tags: python, tkinter

When I write this,

```
x = Button(reglesfr, text="x", background = "white",foreground="red",command=menu)
```

I have this error:

````
  File "c:\Users\ilyas\Documents\defind\menu.py", line 200, in <module>
    x = Button(reglesfr, text="x", background = "white",foreground="red",command=menu)
  File "C:\Users\ilyas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 607, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::button", kw)
  File "C:\Users\ilyas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 552, in __init__
    tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
  File "C:\Users\ilyas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2572, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-background"```
````

Comment: is that a `ttk.Button`? they don't have that attribute, they would require a `ttk.Style` to change their appearance. did you do sth like `from tkinter import *` and then `from tkinter.ttk import *`, don't do that, import what you specifically need or better import only the module

Comment: Thats why wildcard imports are discouragous, tk.Button has the option background while ttk,Button does not.

Comment: thank you very much !!!

Answer (score -3):

Use `bg`, Example:

```py
x = Button(reglesfr, text="x", bg = "white",fg="red",command=menu)
```

And foreground replace it with `fg`.
Check if you use `tkinter.ttk.Button()` or `tkinter.Button()`

Comment: `bg` is the same as `background`, so this is incorrect

Comment: I has this error before, are you imported everything from `tkinter.ttk`?